# Convert/format missing date to complete date

Tags: vba, date, excel

I am trying to write a VBA function to handle missing dates. Dates can be entered in my Excel worksheets as follows:

- 2012
- 12/2012
- 07/04/2012 (This is good, no need to change)

I need to process the missing months/dates like this:

- 2012 --> 01/01/2012
- 12/2012 --> 01/12/2012

Also, the cell where the date is entered should be text and not date, since if its formatted as date it can convert a year only entry to some weird date like 1900.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming column A is in text format, and that the 3 types of formats you gave are the only possible. Note: the formula returns an error if the cell in column A is empty, but it can be fixed if needed.

```
A              B
2012           =DATE(A1,1,1)
12/2012        =DATE(RIGHT(A2,4),LEFT(A2,2),1)
07/04/2012     =DATE(RIGHT(A3,4),LEFT(A3,2),MID(A3,4,2))
ANY FORMAT     =IF(LEN(A4)=4,DATE(A4,1,1),IF(LEN(A4)=7,DATE(RIGHT(A2,4),LEFT(A2,2),1),DATE(RIGHT(A3,4),LEFT(A3,2),MID(A3,4,2))))
```

Comment: Thanks! seems great, but what I want is to use it in VBA not in the excel sheet itself. how can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

you can use the DateSerial function to build a date object like this: DateSerial(year, month, day).

In order to get the parts, use a split on the input string like this Split(inputstring, "/") then you can use the returned array elements as building blocks for whatever handling you want to perform.

Putting it together...

```
Public Function DateFromString(inputString as String) as Date
  Dim dateParts as String()
  dateParts = Split(inputString, "/")
  Dim year as Integer
  Dim month as Integer
  Dim day as Integer

  If Ubound(dateParts) = 3 Then
    month = dateParts(1)
    day = dateParts(2)
    year = dateParts(3)
  Else If Ubound(dateParts) = 2 Then
    day = dateParts(1)
    year = dateParts(2)
  Else If Ubound(dateParts) = 1 Then
    year = dateParts(1)
  End If

  <check for missing date elements and provide values per business rules here...>

  DateFromString = DateSerial(year, month, day)
End Function
```

I haven't tested this code, but it should get you pointed in the right direction.

Comment: I think split has LBound = 0, so your conditions would be UBound = 2, 1 and 0 respectively.